Azure DevOps pipeline task condition checking for empty string
I have this template :
parameters:
  gitTag: ' '

stages:
- stage: CreationTag

  jobs:
  - job: Tag
    pool:
      name: Default

    steps:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'gitTag parameter trim'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | 
          $trimmedGitTag = "${{parameters.gitTag}}".Trim()
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=trimmedGitTag]$trimmedGitTag"
          Write-Output "Trimed parameter = '$trimmedGitTag'"
      
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Creation du tag Git'      
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Output "Trimed parameter = '$(trimmedGitTag)'"
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne('$(trimmedGitTag)', ''))

I receive a parameter from the main stage but it can be empty ou contains only whistespaces. So in the first task, I trim the parameter in a variable. In the second task, I added a condition so the precedent task mut have succeeded and the trimed parameter value must not be equal to ''.
The first step executes and outputs "Trimed parameter = ''" in the console.
My problem is that the second task still executes, while it shouldn't. And it also display the same value ("Trimed parameter = ''") with the Write-Output.
What would be the problem here? Or is it anither way to ensure taht a task is only performed when a parameter has a value other than empty or whitespaces?
EDIT
I changed the default value of the parameter to a blank space as a workaround for an optional parameter. In the original post, I have used an empty string ''. I want to be able to manage the cases where :

the user dont input anything
the user inputs only whitespaces (any lenght so '    ' shouldn't run the task
the user inputs a valid value but begins or ends with whitespaces that will crash my tasks. That's why I need a Trim()


Instead of:
condition: and(succeeded(), ne('$(trimmedGitTag)', ''))

Try:
condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['trimmedGitTag'], ''))

Or, as an alternative:
- ${{ if replace(parameters.gitTag, ' ') }}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Do something with the tag'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $trimmedGitTag="${{ parameters.gitTag }}".Trim()
        Write-Output "Trimed parameter = '$trimmedGitTag'"


@PatriceCote are you using templates and passing the right parameters? Because I've tested my code and it was working. Double-check if you're passing all the parameters correctly.

Also, are you setting and using the variable in the same job?

OK, it was juste a typo, my mistake. Your solution with the condition works great. I didn't get that the variable was added to "variables" array. Thanks a lot for your help!

You are defaulting the value to ''. This means that if none is provided then it will result in ''.
I think leveraging PowerShell here is overcomplicating what you are attempting to do. What I would recommend doing is putting an if statement on the task
steps:
- ${{ if paraemters.Tag }}:
  - task:someTask@1

You currently are leveraging conditions which will evaluate at pipeline execution and typically will show a status of skipped if the condition is not filled. By leveraging an if condition it is evaluated at compilation time and as such the tasks that aren't satisfied won't even be loaded into the job.
Some resources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-run-a-step
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-if-expressions-and-conditions/ba-p/3737159

Careful - ${{ if parameters.Tag }}: will evaluate to True if the string is NOT empty. See Type casting - String.

Valid however, 1.) it is being set to a default value of '' and an assumption w/ a name like githubTag that it will not be whitespaces.

Yes default value is an empty string, but maybe it's just an example. Don't make too many assumptions about how people will use the pipeline (or a template). Better be safe than sorry :-)

@DreadedFrost I used an If statement for my tests, but I still think the condition is a lot clearer and more readable

Also I changed the default value for ' ' as I want it to ba an optional parameter. I will edit the post

Out of curiosity why change it? Setting the default to '' effectively makes it optional. If no value is present it's empty.
